# How can I check if xref-find-references is using the correct TAGS file?

Tags: ctags

I'm only getting

```
Unable to find symbol
```

, no matter what I try

I first need to figure how which TAGS file it is using. I have generated a TAGS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `C-h v tags-file-name` for either a buffer-local or a global value.

Then if necessary, try `M-x visit-tags-table` and specify the file you want. `C-h f visit-tags-table` says:

```
Tell tags commands to use tags table file FILE.
FILE should be the name of a file created with the ‘etags’ program.
A directory name is ok too; it means file TAGS in that directory.

Normally M-x visit-tags-table sets the global value of ‘tags-file-name’.
With a prefix arg, set the buffer-local value instead.  When called
from Lisp, if the optional arg LOCAL is non-nil, set the local value.
When you find a tag with M-x find-tag, the buffer it finds the tag
in is given a local value of this variable which is the name of the tags
file the tag was in.
```

EDIT: <s>it turns out that the OP had used `ctags` to produce the `TAGS` file, instead of using `etags`. As  `man ctags` says: `The  etags  program  is  used  to  create  a tag table file, in a format understood by emacs(1); the ctags program is used to create a similar table in a  format  understood by vi(1).`</s> The above is the case for the `etags/ctags` distributed with Emacs, but it may not be the case for other implementations. The story is more complicated and is still under investigation (see comment below). I'll update this EDIT note once the investigation is done.

Comment: It's listing the correct TAGS file, but it's still not finding anything;) I'll open a new thread on that. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I generated the file with "ctags -Re . *.cs", but it seems to work with "find . -name "*.cs" -print | etags -". I'll dig deeper another time, cause it seems to work. Thanks;)

Comment: `man ctags` says: `The  etags  program  is  used  to  create  a tag table file, in a format understood by emacs(1); the ctags program is used to create a similar table in a  format  understood by vi(1).`

Comment: Right, but it also says "To use ctags with emacs, you must supply the '-e' parameter to instruct ctags to generate an emacs tag file."

Comment: There is no mention of that in my `ctags/etags` man page - in fact `-e` does not appear at all as an option. IIRC correctly, you are on macOS (?), so there might be a BSD ctags that's included in it and maybe `ctags -e` is supposed to invoke `etags` instead, but I am not able to check. Feel free to edit the answer and add your findings in that case.

Comment: I found that comment on the wiki, https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildTags and no, I'm not on macOS. I'm on NixOS;)

Comment: Does your `ctags` support `-e`? If I run `ctags -e`, I get `Invalid option`. It may be that the information on the EmacsWiki is outdated.

Comment: See [ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) on Wikipedia for history and versions. I use the etags/ctags implementation that is distributed with Emacs (I build from source) and that does not support `-e`. There is `exuberant ctags` which was maintained until 2009, and there is `universal ctags` which is an `exuberant` [fork](https://ctags.io/) available from [Github](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags). I'll try to build `universal ctags` and try it out. Depending on how it goes, I'll update the Emacs WIki.